# Ubuntu system ruby upgrade borked rvm, how do I fix this?

Tags: ubuntu, rvm

I upgraded my system Ruby to Ruby 1.9.1 and inadvertently killed my rvm. My old system was 1.8. Now when I try to run programs that pull from the gems I have in ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems, I see:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- hola (LoadError)
```

from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from test.rb:1:in`'
I included this line in my .bashrc file

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

But when I run it, I get this message:

```
rvm_is_a_shell_function: command not found
```

Also, when I do rvm list, I no longer see rvm 1.9.3, just an empty list (I reinstalled rvm).

How can I restore things to the way they used to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get back the ruby with:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194 --install --default
```